# Hydration error with nextjs and prisma when listing items from my db

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

i am trying to get all items from my db and list them, but it gives me this hydration  error: `Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error`](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error%60), I wonder why this happenes and how can I fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";

const ListingsPage = async () => {
  const listings = await prismadb.jobListing.findMany();

  return (
    <div
      className="grid  lg:grid-cols-2 gap-3 md:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 px-4 "
      suppressHydrationWarning
    >
      {listings.map(async (listing: any, index) => (
        <div className="m-5" key={index}>
          <div
            suppressHydrationWarning
            className="group mx-2 mt-10 grid max-w-screen-md grid-cols-12 space-x-8 overflow-hidden rounded-lg border py-8 text-gray-700 shadow transition hover:shadow-lg sm:mx-auto"
          >
            <a
              href="#"
              className="order-2 col-span-1 mt-4 -ml-14 text-left text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-700 sm:-order-1 sm:ml-4"
            >
              <div className="group relative h-16 w-16 overflow-hidden rounded-lg">
                <img
                  src={listing.companyLogoSrc}
                  alt=""
                  className="h-full w-full object-cover text-gray-700"
                />
              </div>
            </a>
            <div className="col-span-11 flex flex-col pr-8 text-left sm:pl-4">
              <h3 className="text-sm text-gray-600">{listing.companyName}</h3>
              <a
                href="#"
                className="mb-3 overflow-hidden pr-7 text-lg font-semibold sm:text-xl"
              >
                {" " + listing.PositionName + " "}
              </a>
              <p className="overflow-hidden pr-7 text-sm">
                {listing.PositionDescription}
              </p>

              <div className="mt-5 flex flex-col space-y-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 sm:flex-row sm:items-center sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-2">
                <div>
                  Experience:
                  <span className="ml-2 mr-3 rounded-full bg-green-100 px-2 py-0.5 text-green-900">
                    {" "}
                    2 Years{" "}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  Salary:
                  <span className="ml-2 mr-3 rounded-full bg-blue-100 px-2 py-0.5 text-blue-900">
                    {listing.Salary}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ListingsPage;
```

I have put surpressHydrationError, but it doesn't work